# Send Text message automatically from iphone application

Tags: iphone, sms

I am sending text message using MFMessageComposeViewController in my iphone application.

Is there any way to send text message automatically without prompt user to send by pressing send button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do this in iOS without using private APIs.

Comment: there is no other way then default composer?

Comment: No. Not without using private APIs. Imagine an app you use sends a message to someone without you knowing.

Comment: i have seen an app on app store called iSMSPro, it has its own composer, i need something like that... there is a text box and send button on send button user can send sms to his selected friends